# Unit Testing Custom Assertion Class - Failure Case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a custom assertion class that I'm currently unit testing.

```
public static class AssertionExtensions
{
    public static void ShouldHaveAttributeApplied<T>(this T obj, Type attributeType)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), attributeType));
    }
}
```

The tests for this class are:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Called_For_Class_Validates_Pass_Correctly()
    {
        var obj = new FakeClass();
        obj.ShouldHaveAttributeApplied(typeof(FakeClassAttribute));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Called_For_Class_Validates_Fail_Correctly()
    {
        var obj = new FakeClass();
        obj.ShouldHaveAttributeApplied(typeof(UnappliedFakeClassAttribute));
    }
```

The test `When_Called_For_Class_Validates_Fail_Correctly` fails as expected, but how do I mark this fail as a pass in the test suite?

This is using C# / MSTest.

Comment: What do you mean by marking fail as a pass? Fail is a fail.

Comment: The test When_Called_For_Class_Validates_Fail_Correctly Fails, which is what I expect. However, in the context of this test, failing is the success condition of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `ExpectedException` attribute with the exception set to `AssertionFailedException` makes the test pass as intended.

Usage:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(AssertFailedException))]
public void When_Called_For_Class_Validates_Fail_Correctly()
{
    var obj = new FakeClass();
    obj.ShouldHaveAttributeApplied(typeof(UnappliedFakeClassAttribute));
}
```